# Setting layout and title in sails

Tags: javascript, node.js, sails.js

I want to fetch a view and its specific layout in controller and once that is done,i want to use variables inside the controller in the view and layout.

I want to use `title` in the layout and other variables in the view.

Currently i have this and i cant change the title in my layout

```
hi: function (req, res) {
      res.view('noder/home',{ layout: 'layout' },{
   locals: {
      title : 'hello'
   }
})},
```

How can i change the title in the layout on controller basis and use other variables within my view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
hi: function(req, res) {
        res.view('noder/home', {
            layout: 'layout',
            title: 'hello'
        });
    }
```

Make sure your `layout.ejs` file has following line in `title` tag

```
<title><%- title %></title>
```